# Installing PHP on Linux and php.ini file

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have installed PHP with Apache 2.2 on my Linux machine and all works fine following guide [here](http://www.php.net/manual/it/install.unix.apache2.php)

During the installation I had to copy the `php.ini-development` file into `/usr/local/lib/php.ini`, the question is why? Why exactly in this directory?

Comment: Err… because if you put it in an arbitrary directory, then PHP won't know where to find it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default locations of the PHP configurations vary greatly by distribution. In any case, `phpinfo()` will allways tell you where is looks for your configurations.
So, create file with extension ".php" in your webroot and past this into it:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Also, the default php.ini files contain plenty od usefull comments. Just read them and change what you need. Differences between dev and prod environments are usually only the verbosity. They show and log different ammounts of errors. Production usually shows no error at all.

(Debian and many other distributions put the PHP config into /etc/php5. This is actually the most reasonable place for configurations, but stick with what your distribution uses.)

Answer (score 0):

The document you link to says this

```
You may edit your .ini file to set PHP options. [...]

If you instead choose php.ini-production, be certain to read the list of changes within, as they affect how PHP behaves.`
```

Have you tried something like

`vi /usr/local/lib/php.ini`

to see what's in it?

Maybe you need to read http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php

Answer (score 0):

You copied a default PHP.ini file, php.ini-development, to the standard 'php.ini' file in the location '/usr/local/lib/' the guide http://www.php.net/manual/it/install.unix.apache2.php 
expected the php.ini file to be.

The php.ini file is a configuration file used by PHP when it is launched (runtime)